# VB why DBnull? Operator '*' is not defined for string "11106.9" and type 'DBNull'

Tags: vb.net

i just want calculate amount with percent on database access.
this my code

```
 xlWorksheet.Range("AI" & CurrentRow2).Value = Format(CDbl(strGetAccrualAllocation*ADORS_Temp1.Fields("PERCENTAGE").Value).ToString("N2"))
```

and this error respond

> System.InvalidCastException: Operator '*' is not defined for string
>   "11106.9" and type 'DBNull'.

thankyou

Comment: You can't multiply a null by a string.  So I assume `ADORS_Temp1.Fields("PERCENTAGE").Value` is null and `strGetAccrualAllocation` is a string.  Without seeing how you are setting `ADORS_Temp1.Fields("PERCENTAGE")` there's no real way of knowing **why** it is a null.  (Perhaps that's what's in your database.  Perhaps there is an error in your query.  Perhaps you have accidentally nulled the field somehow.  So many possibilities.)

Comment: why my PERCENTAGE can Null value? , PERCENTAGE type Data is  Short Text and i put the value should be "0.51231" but why null :(

Comment: Just showing the one line of code where you try to **use** the percentage is not going to help us work out for you **why** it is null.  Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46463781/edit) the question to provide sufficient information for us to help you.

Comment: just check if its null and give it a zero, but obviously if you divide zero by a number you are also going to get an error. i suggest trapping the error, so around that one line of code and if it gives an error on zero divsion then catch the exception and put a zero into the field instead of its calculation, because obviously the arithmetic is stupid.

Comment: You really should be developing with [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) to prevent these kinds of errors at design-time instead of run-time.

Answer (score 0):

It is always wise to check data used in a calculation for NULL.  I often use the inline if to do that, for example:

```
   IIF(IsDBNull(MyValue),0,MyValue)
```

If MyValue is null, zero is returned, if not, the value of MyValue is returned.

Or if you need to indicate to the user that a value is null:

```
If IsDBNull(MyValue) Then
    'message to user that vaslue is null or some other action
Else
    'perforn calculation
End If
```

When using a string of numeric characters, implicit conversion from string to value will take place.  If there is any chance that the string could contain anything other than numeric characters, you should test for that, otherwise another error will be generated.

Comment: `IIF` shouldn't be used any more, it is a holdover from the old VB6 days, there is a [proper `If` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/if-operator) now.

Comment: Just an example, use whatever works .... the point is to check the data.

Comment: You should strive to add *correct* and *best practice* answers on this site, as it is a tool used by many people to learn.  We have a duty to teach good code.

Comment: IIF is still in wide use and has not been depreciated.  The difference between the two is the IF function shortcircuts, it only evaluates what it needs to satisfy the condition, where IIF evaluates all parameters.