# Nested Loop Issue

Tags: vb.net-2010

I get the below error when run the code , I made nested loop between two tables when the code started the loop started but when it end in table 2 the below error appears

Operator '=' is not defined for string "9" and type 'DBNull'.

```
    Do While Not rs1.EOF()
        Do While Not rs2.EOF()
        If rs1("Number").Value = rs2("CDNumber").Value Then
                rs1("Matched").Value = "Yes"
                rs1.Update()
                rs2.MoveFirst()
                rs1.MoveNext()

            End If
            rs2.MoveNext()
        Loop
    Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error arises because, at some point, your loop tries to compare a string and a null value.  I don't believe this is a valid comparison.  Check your data set for NULL values.

It likely happens at line: `If rs1("Number").Value = rs2("CDNumber").Value Then`

**Relevant Link:**
[VB.Net DBNull and String error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46463781/vb-why-dbnull-operator-is-not-defined-for-string-11106-9-and-type-dbnull)

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

It is always wise to check data used in a calculation for NULL. for example:

```
 IIF(IsDBNull(MyValue),0,MyValue)
```

If MyValue is null, zero is returned, if not, the value of MyValue is returned

```
Do While Not rs1.EOF()
    Do While Not rs2.EOF()
    If     
IIF(IsDBNull(rs1("Number").Value),0,rs1("Number").Value) =IIF(IsDBNull(rs2("CDNumber").Value),0,rs2("CDNumber").Value)   Then
            rs1("Matched").Value = "Yes"
            rs1.Update()
            rs2.MoveFirst()
            rs1.MoveNext()

        End If
        rs2.MoveNext()
    Loop
Loop
```

**Solution 2: Adding the extra validation using If condition for IsDbNull values.**

```
Do While Not rs1.EOF()
    Do While Not rs2.EOF()
        If NOT IsDbNull(rs1("Number")) And Also  NOT IsDbNull(rs2("CDNumber")) Then
            If IIF(IsDBNull(rs1("Number").Value),0,rs1("Number").Value) =IIF(IsDBNull(rs2("CDNumber").Value),0,rs2("CDNumber").Value)   Then
                    rs1("Matched").Value = "Yes"
                    rs1.Update()
                    rs2.MoveFirst()
                    rs1.MoveNext()

                End If
        End If
        rs2.MoveNext()
    Loop
Loop
```

**Solution 3: Using only If condition for IsDbNull values.**

```
Do While Not rs1.EOF()
    Do While Not rs2.EOF()
        If rs1("Number").Value = rs2("CDNumber").Value Then
            rs1("Matched").Value = "Yes"
            rs1.Update()
            rs2.MoveFirst()
            rs1.MoveNext()

        End If
    rs2.MoveNext()
    Loop
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew E. Miller and Rishab the code work fine but when the first record in table 1 is not matched with records in table 2 , its not skipped to the next record in table 1 to match it with table 2 can you help with code correction ?

Comment: Hi @Mahmoud Please check the updated solution hope it helps you out

Comment: Thanks Rishab I will try it and let you know the results however could you please look in the initial code and see if it's correct or need some amendment, as I told you if the first record is not matched the system not skip to the next record in table 1 to match it